# Decode gzipped web page retrieved via cURL in PHP

Tags: php, encoding, gzip, decoding

I'm retrieving a gzipped web page via curl, but when I output the retrieved content to the browser I just get the raw gzipped data. How can I decode the data in PHP?

One method I found was to write the content to a tmp file and then ...

```
$f = gzopen($filename,"r");
$content = gzread($filename,250000);
gzclose($f);
```

.... but man, there's got to be a better way.

Edit: This isn't a file, but a gzipped html page returned by a web server.

Comment: Is the file itself gzipped, or is the server gzipping it for transfer?

Comment: Instead of decoding the gzip data, could you just send the correct headers so that the browser recognizes it properly?

Or, if you don't want it gzipped in the first place, tell cURL not to ask for gzipped data by setting CURLOPT_ENCODING to "identity".

Comment: There is a PHP function called **gzdecode** that applies to strings, not files.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

The following command enables cURL's "auto encoding" mode, where it will announce to the server which encoding methods it supports (via the `Accept-Encoding` header), and then automatically decompress the response for you:

```
// Allow cURL to use gzip compression, or any other supported encoding
// A blank string activates 'auto' mode
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , '');
```

If you specifically want to force the header to be `Accept-Encoding: gzip` you can use this command instead:

```
// Allow cURL to use gzip compression, or any other supported encoding
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , 'gzip');
```

Read more in the [PHP documentation: curl_setopt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Thanks to commenters for helping improve this answer.

Comment: Just to note that this option sets the `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header   on the request *and* uncompresses the response if it is compressed (it may not be), so it is indeed all you need to do.

Comment: Perfect solution for CURL.

Comment: Setting it to `'gzip'` will *always* send `Accept-Encoding: gzip`, even when your PHP version doesn't support decoding gzip (you'll get the compressed data then). If you set it to `''` (empty string), curl will automatically announce and decode all encodings that it supports.

Comment: @AndreKR - that's brilliant.  Just read this in the docs *"If an empty string, "", is set, a header containing all supported encoding types is sent."*

Comment: I updated your great answer to be a bit more thorough, based on the comments above. Hope that's OK!

Answer (score 5):

Versatile GUNZIP function:

```
   function gunzip($zipped) {
      $offset = 0;
      if (substr($zipped,0,2) == "\x1f\x8b")
         $offset = 2;
      if (substr($zipped,$offset,1) == "\x08")  {
         # file_put_contents("tmp.gz", substr($zipped, $offset - 2));
         return gzinflate(substr($zipped, $offset + 8));
      }
      return "Unknown Format";
   }
```

Example of integrating function with CURL:

```
      $headers_enabled = 1;
      curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER,  $headers_enabled)
      $ret = curl_exec($c);

      if ($headers_enabled) {
         # file_put_contents("preungzip.html", $ret);

         $sections = explode("\x0d\x0a\x0d\x0a", $ret, 2);
         while (!strncmp($sections[1], 'HTTP/', 5)) {
            $sections = explode("\x0d\x0a\x0d\x0a", $sections[1], 2);
         }
         $headers = $sections[0];
         $data = $sections[1];

         if (preg_match('/^Content-Encoding: gzip/mi', $headers)) {
            printf("gzip header found\n");
            return gunzip($data);
         }
      }

      return $ret;
```