# Parser problem PHP

Tags: php, parsing

I am going to write a parser that is going to get information from a website.

However something is wrong with this website and soon as i fetch the information and put it in a file, it's all gibberish.

The website is anidb.net

Could anyone tell me why i get gibberish instead of the HTML?

My code

```
<?php
$url = 'http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&aid=854';

file_put_contents("file.txt", file_get_contents($url));
?>
```

May i also add that using the browser's View Source function i see the HTML.

Comment: Please specify the result; gibbrish is very unspecific

Comment: You would have to show the gibberish to tell for sure, but chances are that the content you're receiving is gzip encoded.

Comment: Юэ+=ґw“±•¤№kЖ'»MчљЏ™фљir}ЪбJґНXўt"е]зЇ?Ђ)‹ЦжЪ—µшЃ That's it(if you can see the characters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked the headers on the page that you specified and it's returning:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

That means the 'gibberish' you're seeing is indeed gzip encoded. Here's another thread that should help you out:
[Decode gzipped web page retrieved via cURL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310650/decode-gzipped-web-page-retrieved-via-curl-in-php)