# How to speed up cURL in php?

Tags: php, rest, twitter

I'm trying to get embed tweet from Twitter. So, I'm using cURL to get the json back. I wrote a little test but the test takes around 5 seconds as well as when I run locally. So, I'm not sure what am I doing wrong here.

```
public function get_tweet_embed($tw_id) {

    $json_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?id={$tw_id}&align=left&omit_script=true&hide_media=false";

    $ch = curl_init( $json_url );
    $start_time = microtime(TRUE);
    $JSON = curl_exec($ch);
    $end_time = microtime(TRUE);
    echo $end_time - $start_time; //5.7961111068726

    return $this->get_html($JSON);
}

private function get_html($embed_json) {
    $JSON_Data = json_decode($embed_json,true);
    $tw_embed_code = $JSON_Data["html"];
    return $tw_embed_code;
}
```

When I paste the link and test it from the browser it's really fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With respect to environment, I've observed in PHP that cURL typically runs very fast in most environments except in places where there is low CPU and there is slower network performance. For example, on localhost on my MAMP installation, curl is fast, on a larger amazon instance, curl is fast. But on a small crappy hosting, i've seen it have performance issues where it is noticeably slower to connect. Though, i'm not sure exactly *why* that is slower. Also, it sure wasn't 5 seconds slower.

to help determine if its PHP or your environment, you should try interacting with curl via the command line. At least that you'll be able to rule out PHP code being the problem if its still 5 seconds.

Comment: You were right it seems to be the problem with DNS. Now it's faster.

Answer (score 31):

The best speed up I've ever had was reusing the same curl handle. 
Replace `$ch = curl_init( $json_url );` with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);`. Then outside the functions have one `$ch = curl_init();`. You'll need to make `$ch` global in the functions to access it.

Reusing the curl handle keeps the connection to the server open. This only works if the server is the same between requests, as yours are.

Comment: I can verify that this solution cut my total execution time down from 22 seconds to 7 seconds (~30 API calls). Best speed up. Thank you! Instead of using global scope, I set it to a property of my class.

Comment: Thank you! reusing the curl handle was the trick for me.

Comment: thanks, the code by @Michael Sivolobov which implements this idea, helps me

Answer (score 21):

The final solution for speed up is this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
```

Regards

Comment: why is this supposed to be faster?

Comment: I didn't see any improvement with this option

Comment: This should be the real solution, though if system is configured correctly curl will work just fine otherwise ipv6 resolve taking too much time then falls back to ipv4

Comment: This solved my problem, having the request take around 6 seconds, down to around 1 sec

Answer (score 10):

Try to set 
    `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,  '')`
it's enable gzip compression

Comment: It's still not faster than before. :-(

Comment: Try download page from another site, maybe problem in local web server.

Comment: is there a way to check that? im using Apache 2 the n Centos 5.8

Comment: It seems 50% faster for me with this options, but I guess it will depend of the size of your response. My request is a file of 500k, gziped it's 22k so it makes the transfer faster for me. If your response is very small, gzip may be useless and because it will be the same size and so the same time to transfer.
Thanks ncs

Comment: More information on this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310650/decode-gzipped-web-page-retrieved-via-curl-in-php#comment71125013_2849331

Comment: WOW! it was 3.5-3.9s after 0.8-1.2s !!! Man, thank you !!!))

Answer (score 8):

To speed up cURL I recommend create special class for API (e.g. `ApiClient`) and use one shared cURL handler, only change URL for every request. Also cut off requests for name resolving and use gzipped response.

I needed to process about 1 million entities every day from one API-server that limits us to use only one concurrent connection. I created that class. I hope it will help others in optimising their curl requests.

```php
class ApiClient
{
    const CURL_TIMEOUT = 3600;
    const CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 30;
    const HOST = 'api.example.com';
    const API_TOKEN = 'token';

    /** @var resource CURL handler. Reused every time for optimization purposes */
    private $ch;
    /** @var string URL for API. Calculated at creating object for optimization purposes */
    private $url;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->url = 'https://' . self::HOST . '/v1/entity/view?token=' . self::API_TOKEN . '&id=';
                                // Micro-optimization: every concat operation takes several milliseconds
                                // But for millions sequential requests it can save a few seconds
        $host = [implode(':', [ // $host stores information for domain names resolving (like /etc/hosts file)
            self::HOST, // Host that will be stored in our "DNS-cache"
            443, // Default port for HTTPS, can be 80 for HTTP
            gethostbyname(self::HOST), // IPv4-address where to point our domain name (Host)
        ])];
        $this->ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');  // This will use server's gzip (compress data)
                                                       // Depends on server. On some servers can not work
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RESOLVE, $host); // This will cut all requests for domain name resolving
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, self::CURL_TIMEOUT); // To not wait extra time if we know
                                                            // that api-call cannot be longer than CURL_TIMEOUT
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, self::CONNECT_TIMEOUT); // Close connection if server doesn't response after CONNECT_TIMEOUT
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // To return output in `curl_exec`
    }

    /** @throws \Exception */
    public function requestEntity($id)
    {
        $url = $this->url . $id;

        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        $data = curl_exec($this->ch);

        if (curl_error($this->ch)) {
            throw new \Exception('cURL error (' . curl_errno($this->ch) . '): ' . curl_error($this->ch));
        }

        return $data;
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        curl_close($this->ch);
    }
}
```

Also if you don't have limitations to have only one connection with server you can use `curl_multi_*` functions.

Comment: Thanks for this piece of code, it is very helpful. speed up my requests 30%+

Comment: I have issues with this approach. In particular, I cannot find info for how to properly reset previously set options (like CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, etc).

Currently (new $curl on each request) — I somply don't set those options if they're not needed for current request =)

Comment: If you have very different requests you should not use this code as it is optimized for similar requests

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
CURLOPT_TCP_FASTOPEN => 1
```

... to activate TCP-Fast-Open.

It was added to cURL 7.49.0, added to PHP 7.0.7.

Comment: how do you set this exactly in PHP?

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TCP_FASTOPEN, true);

Answer (score 2):

Try using with `--ipv4` parameter.

This will force curl to use only ipv-4 and ignore ipv-6 which is still not very compatible with some devices and slows down the process. Adding `--ipv4` to my curl command reduced the cost from 8 seconds to 4 seconds. Which is %50 faster.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to add this too:

```
CURLOPT_ENCODING  =>  'gzip,deflate'
```