# php - characters instead of html

Tags: php, character-encoding

Why does the code below code not print html content?

```
$url = 'http://clashofclans.com';
echo file_get_contents($url);
```

It works in all websites except for `$url`. I get this:

```
‹í}}{ÛÆ±ïÿùÛ[É-á…IÛrŽÍØqzœØO¤º·'ÍÕ ˆ˜$ÔK÷;¿™¾åö9µËÅîìÌì¼íìxúå×o»çÿx÷Rd£á³/žâ¢ ƒñÕi#7P½g_hÚÓQ”Z8¦i”6fYßh7NæwY61¢_fñõiãÿ{nt“Ñ$ÈâËaÔÐÂdœEcêöíËÓ¨w•;Ž
```

Comment: it's gzipped content, used for minimize data transfers over the network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the response content is gzipped.

Try [gzdecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php):

```
gzdecode(file_get_contents($url));
```

Consider using cURL instead, which does the decompression for you and should be more robust, as described in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2849331/277106).