# php curl response show gzip or encoded data

Tags: php, curl

I am using below script to get data from a website. data is return but it is in gzip or some encoded format. I tried to use gzdecode but it is not working on it. is there any way to see clean data from this request.

I use

```
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , 'deflate');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , 'gzip');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , 'br');
```

but none of them is working. below is curl request

```
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.example.com');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , 'deflate');
            $response = curl_exec($ch);

            $d = curl_getinfo( $ch );
```

**curl_getinfo is showing below**

I can see that site is using "br" encoding i.e Content-Encoding: br

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310650/decode-gzipped-web-page-retrieved-via-curl-in-php

Comment: If it is not confidential, please share the real URL and `$header`. I cannot reproduce it with *https://www.example.com*.

Comment: I can see that site is using "br" encoding i.e Content-Encoding: br

Comment: works for me, so giving an url would be nice

Comment: this question is quite old, but I wonder: no answer here helped you in any way?

Comment: I have already answered this below and you commented on that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In header i allowed gzip and deflate only and removed br and it worked for me. So instead of this `$header[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br';`  i used `$header[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate';`

Thanks for help every one.

Comment: you should never post an incomplete question. If we knew that you had filled in `$header` like that (which makes no sense, since you normally use the `CURLOPT_ENCODING` for that - which you used too) we would not have lost tens of minutes of our time trying to figure out how you could fix your problem.

Comment: Sorry sir. will take care next time @WalterTross

Answer (score 0):

[`br`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding) encoding is [Brotli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brotli) encoding. You can pass it in the `Accept-Encoding` header with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , 'br')`, but it won't be handled by `curl`, i.e., you will have to decode the output explicitly.

You can probably use this PHP extension: https://github.com/kjdev/php-ext-brotli

You can also try to use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , 'identity')`, and, if the server you are calling behaves properly, get the data uncompressed.

I guess you've already tried to leave the `Accept-Encoding` header completely out. Unfortunately, according [the specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.4), this does not prevent the output to be encoded.

Answer (score 0):

```
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , 'deflate');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , 'gzip');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , 'br');
```

subsequent calls overwrite the previous value, it doesn't add to the previous value. if you want to support `deflate`, `gzip`, and `br`, then separate them with comma, eg

```
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , 'gzip,deflate,br');
```

however, br is a recent addition to curl, br support was first added to curl at version 7.57.0, released at `November 29 2017`, so you might want to add

```
if(!definied("CURL_VERSION_BROTLI")){
// https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/f762fec323f36fd7da7ad6eddfbbae940ec3229e/include/curl/curl.h#L2720
    define("CURL_VERSION_BROTLI",(1<<23));
}
if(!(curl_version()["features"] & CURL_VERSION_BROTLI)){
    throw new \RuntimeException("this script requires brotli support added to libcurl (added in libcurl version 7.57.0, released November 29 2017), please update your libcurl installation.");
}
```

to ensure that br is actually supported by your php's libcurl, if you require it.