Why do i get random characters as a response to my curl get call in php?
I am trying to get a list of deliveries using this GET call:
https://datalink.hconnect.digital/api-products/basic#get-https-//api.hconnect.digital/ecs/v2/deliveries
Here is a picture if the link is broken in the future
If i var_dump the response i get this:
"tring(22) "��)�L
If i write the response into a txt file using file_put_contents i get this
謟   躋묩ൌ
Here is my code
$AuthJSON = include ("APIAuthenticator.php"); // retrieves the accesstoken with a POST request

$jsonObject = json_decode($AuthJSON, false);

$accessToken = $jsonObject->access_token;
$tokenType = $jsonObject->token_type;

$customerIdParameter = "?customerId=redacted";
$startDateParameter = "&startDate=2024-06-01";//"&startDate=".date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-1 days"));
$endDateParameter = "&endDate=".date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-1 days"));


// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.hconnect.digital/ecs/v2/deliveries".$customerIdParameter.$startDateParameter.$endDateParameter);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: '.$tokenType.' '.$accessToken;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($result);

file_put_contents("GetDeliveriesList_Output.txt", $result);

//return $resultObject;

When i try the API Call in Postman i get the correct JSON with all deliveries.
Also i tried it with Talend at first using the tRESTClient component.
Which looks like this
The output in Talend looks like this
In my php script i tried to convert the encoding to utf-8 from different ones but i only get different gibberish everytime.
Edit after comments:
These are the response Headers
'string(480) "HTTP/2 200
date: Tue, 09 Jul 2024 11:18:10 GMT
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
vary: Accept-Encoding
strict-transport-security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
content-encoding: gzip
x-request-id: d7bd9ad9a947fd97ee68e953dc72a9d8
x-azure-ref: 20240709T111810Z-17cf9458cfbljplp9z04nke6fc00000007sg0000000164kk
x-cache: CONFIG_NOCACHE'

After adding
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
The output is string(2) "[]"
Even though it should be a json Array

Have a look at the response headers. My guess is that the response is compressed.

These are the response Headers
'string(480) "HTTP/2 200
date: Tue, 09 Jul 2024 11:18:10 GMT
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
vary: Accept-Encoding
strict-transport-security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
content-encoding: gzip
x-request-id: d7bd9ad9a947fd97ee68e953dc72a9d8
x-azure-ref: 20240709T111810Z-17cf9458cfbljplp9z04nke6fc00000007sg0000000164kk
x-cache: CONFIG_NOCACHE'

As guessed at its compressed: content-encoding: gzip - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2849331/246342 for the solution.

@Pascal Please add such information to the question, don't add it in the comments.
